# No suitable driver found for "jdbc:oracle:thin:@**** "oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver";

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

here is my java code

```
public static Map<String,String> propertyFileReader() {
    Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = Util.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jdbc.properties");
        prop.load(inputStream);

        final String DB_DRIVER= prop.getProperty("DB_DRIVER");
        final String DB_CONNECTION = prop.getProperty("DB_CONNECTION2");
        final String DB_USER = prop.getProperty("DB_USER");
        final String DB_PASSWORD = prop.getProperty("DB_PASSWORD");

        map.put("DB_DRIVER",DB_DRIVER);
        map.put("DB_CONNECTION",DB_CONNECTION);
        map.put("DB_USER",DB_USER);
        map.put("DB_PASSWORD",DB_PASSWORD);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return map;
}

private static Connection getDBConnection() {
    Map<String , String > map=new HashMap<String, String>();
    map=propertyFileReader();
    String DB_DRIVER=map.get("DB_DRIVER");
    String DB_CONNECTION= map.get("DB_CONNECTION");
    String DB_USER=map.get("DB_USER");
    String DB_PASSWORD=map.get("DB_PASSWORD");
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return dbConnection;
}
```

here is my properties file

```
DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
DB_CONNECTION2 = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.2.5.23:1521:dbslic";
DB_USER = "TSR_MOBILE";
DB_PASSWORD = "TSR_MOBILE";
```

and i added ojdbc6.jar to my buildpath [tried with ojdbc14.jar also]

but there is a error says like below

```
No suitable driver found for "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.2.5.23:1521:dbslic";
"oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver";
No suitable driver found for "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.2.5.23:1521:dbslic";
[ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method loginBlock
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mainService.TSR_WEB_SERVICE.loginBlock(TSR_WEB_SERVICE.java:416)
    ... 25 more
```

please help me to sort out this issue

Comment: You added it to your buildpath, this is good to satisfy the compile time dependency, should you have one. Did you also pack it in your tomcat's lib folder so you have the driver available at runtime?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using wrong package to refer `OracleDriver` class
Change

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

To

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

[From oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html) class definition

```
public class OracleDriver
              extends oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

The Oracle JDBC driver class that implements the `java.sql.Driver` interface.

Answer (score 5):

Use this as Oracle Driver

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

instead of

```
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a "bit" late, but the accepted answer is not correct, so I post this for anybody unfortunate enough to attempt to copy/paste the code and wondering what went wrong.

The accepted answer is so far correct that

> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

is deprecated, but it is still working in 2020. The problem with the posted code is that the properties file is using semicolons and quotation marks, which are [not valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties). So changing the properties file from

```
DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
DB_CONNECTION2 = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.2.5.23:1521:dbslic";
DB_USER = "TSR_MOBILE";
DB_PASSWORD = "TSR_MOBILE";
```

to

```
DB_DRIVER = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
DB_CONNECTION2 = jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.2.5.23:1521:dbslic
DB_USER = SR_MOBILE
DB_PASSWORD = TSR_MOBILE
```

makes the error go away.